# Reducing the size of boot disk on google cloud instance with Plesk

Tags: google-cloud-platform, plesk, plesk-onyx

i would like to resize the SSD boot disk of my Google Cloud instance from 500 GB to 150 GB. The instance has Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS and Plesk Onyx installed and a web and mail server is running which is currently my biggest problem.

My idea is to create a new instance and add a mirror of the current disk as a boot disk on the new instance. But how do I mirror the disk without a downtime of the mail and web server? Or if I have to stop both services which is the best way to mirror the disk?

Any experiences? Or tips?

500GB SSD is more expensive than we thought, this is the reason why we have to reduce the disk size.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the downtime, I can suggest the following action plan:

1. Deploy a new instance with the required parameters.
2. Perform a migration to the new instance. You can find [documentation here](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/migration-guide/introduction.75496/), and while it may seem complex, when you have two instances with the same Plesk version and the same list of installed components, it is a pretty straightforward process.
3. When the migration is finished, switch routing from the public IP or IPs to a new instance.
4. Make sure that everything works fine and get rid of the overpriced instance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, sounds good. I am stucked with the migration tool. Can't connect to the source server. SSH is not working: Failed to connect to the source server 'source' by SSH: not a valid EC private key file. sudo ssh-copy-id is not working with gcloud and root as a user

Comment: The quickest way would be to enable root login and SSH authentication via a password on a source server.